# How does the typeclass bimap not have a circular definition

Tags: haskell

What key intuition am I missing to understand this code? I do not understand how these compose. first expects a function (a->c) and constructed type (f a b). Yet, second yields (f a d). Furthermore, first and second are defined in terms of bimap which seems circular.

```
class Bifunctor f where
  bimap :: (a -> c) -> (b -> d) -> f a b -> f c d
  bimap g h = first g . second h
  first :: (a -> c) -> f a b -> f c b
  first g = bimap g id
  second :: (b -> d) -> f a b -> f a d
  second = bimap id
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`second` is [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). You can write the implied parameter and it will be symmetrical with `first`.

```
first g = bimap g id
second g = bimap id g
```

As for your question about whether the definitions are circular, the answer is yes. They are circular. According to a strict reading of the Haskell standard, the following implementation is correct

```
data F a b = F a b

instance Bifunctor F -- No functions implemented; take all three defaults
```

That will compile, according to the Haskell standard. But any attempt to call `first`, `second`, or `bimap` will bottom out, since they'll just call each other forever.

However, if you look at the [source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/src/Data.Bifunctor.html#Bifunctor) for `Bifunctor`, there's another little annotation.

```
{-# MINIMAL bimap | first, second #-}
```

This is not an ordinary comment. This is a special instruction directed at GHC (the most popular Haskell compiler). GHC in particular supports minimal directives. This declares that an instance of `Bifunctor` is only complete if it implements *at least* `bimap` or both `first` and `second`. So on GHC, if you fail to satisfy that condition in your own `instance`, you'll get a compiler error. This is also reflected in [the Hackage docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html#t:Bifunctor)

> **Minimal complete definition**
>
> ```
> bimap | first, second
> ```

The expectation is that you, as the programmer, override some of these defaults, and the remaining defaults can just silently fall into place.

You can see the same behavior more directly in the built-in typeclass [`Eq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.9.0/docs/src/GHC.Classes.html#Eq)

```
class  Eq a  where
    (==), (/=)           :: a -> a -> Bool

    {-# INLINE (/=) #-}
    {-# INLINE (==) #-}
    x /= y               = not (x == y)
    x == y               = not (x /= y)
    {-# MINIMAL (==) | (/=) #-}
```

Both `(==)` and `(/=)` are implemented in terms of each other, and there's a `MINIMAL` directive at the bottom indicating that any instance must implement at least one of the two functions.